# Get every folder inside path

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, path, string-matching

I just want to tell my Django project that the .html file it want can be find in any folder inside "/templates". I know this can be done with a simple pattern like

```
allfolders = "/templates/*"
```

or

```
allfolders '/templates/$'
```

or

```
allfolders = 'templates/^$'
```

I really can't remember the correct way of doing it, its just a simple string manipulation that can tell "The file is inside any folder inside the folder '/templates' without any imports being needed. Thats because i want to organize my templates folder so i can have different folders inside it to point me what type of html is this or from what project, things like that, organization propose.

Thanks for your attention and sorry for the lack of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make any regular expressions or a possible matching string for templates folder. Django, by default search for possible sub-directories and html documents in a **templates** folder. Just put your html documents in there, make subdirectories if needed. All you need to do is to pass the request received from `urls.py` in `views.py` to `templates/subdirectory/document.html`. Something like this:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'subdirectory/document.html', {})
```

The string *subdirectory/document.hml* means **templates/subdirectory/document.html**.

**UPDATE**: If you are trying to directly pass the request to a possible html document from `urls.py` using `direct_to_templates`, you can do that so by adding a slash like this:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r"^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "subdirectory/document.html"}),
)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. But make sure you don't include a slash in the start of `templates`. Do it from `/templates/` to `templates/....`.

Comment: I'll give a try for it, but that is what i was trying to do, thanks a lot